# Send a file from react-native to webview

Tags: react-native, android-webview

I have a file about (300 or more mb) I would like to send it to the `webview` in `react-native` app.

I know about `indectjavascript` but it only send string and converting a file of this size to bas64string is not really a solution.

I would like to send it as an array and convert it to blob in js thereafter.

Is there really no way of doing this?

By the way, the file is not included in the asset folder, it's the user files.